# Sed command for merging lines, in reverse, and with semicolon added in between

Tags: regex, sed

I would like know how to do this job with a sed command:

**Input:**

```
http://www.google.com

Google

linktesting

Testing
```

**Output:**

```
Google ; http://www.google.com

Testing ; linktesting
```

so second line before first one and  `;`  added in between.

Comment: Are there really empty lines in input and output, or was that because you didn't have code formatting at first?

Comment: tac will print a file with lines in reverse order, sed 'G;x;H' lines.txt does something similar.

Comment: no empty lines , thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your input and output files *really* have empty lines, this would do it (GNU sed):

```
$ sed -r '/^$/d;N;N;s/^(.*)\n\n(.*)$/\2 ; \1/;$!s/$/\n/' infile
Google ; http://www.google.com

Testing ; linktesting
```

The `-r` (extended regular expressions) is so I don't have to quote my parentheses; the rest works as follows:

```
/^$/d    # Delete empty line; starts new cycle
N        # Append empty line to pattern space
N        # Append second text line to pattern space

# Rearrange lines, remove empty line
s/^(.*)\n\n(.*)$/\2 ; \1/

$!s/$/\n/ # Append newline, unless we're on the last line
```

If, as I suspect, there aren't any empty lines in input and output, this simplifies to

```
$ sed -r 'N;s/^(.*)\n(.*)$/\2 ; \1/' infile
Google ; http://www.google.com
Testing ; linktesting
```

Just appending the next line and rearranging both lines with a substitution.

Answer (score 1):

sed is for simple substitutions on individual lines, that is all. Just use one of these for clarity, robustness, portability, performance, maintainability and most other desirable criteria for software:

If no blank lines:

```
$ awk 'NR%2{url=$0;next} {print $0" ; "url}' file
Google ; http://www.google.com
Testing ; linktesting
```

If blank lines:

```
$ awk '!NF{next} ++cnt%2{url=$0;next} {print $0" ; "url}' file
Google ; http://www.google.com
Testing ; linktesting
```

Add `"\n"` after `url` in the print statements if you want a blank line between output lines.

Answer (score 0):

Consider the following two cases:

---

**Case 1:** If there are really empty lines in input and output:

```
$ cat File
http://www.google.com

Google

linktesting

Testing
```

Then, you can do the following:

```
$ sed 'N;s/\n/ /' File | sed 'N;s/\(.*\)\n\(.*\)/\2 ; \1\n/'
Google  ; http://www.google.com 

Testing ; linktesting
```

---

**Case 2:** If there are no empty lines in input and output:

```
$ cat File
http://www.google.com
Google
linktesting
Testing
```

Then, you can do the following:

```
$ sed 'N;s/\(.*\)\n\(.*\)/\2 ; \1/' File
Google  ; http://www.google.com 
Testing ; linktesting
```

---

In case 1, first `sed` removes empty lines while the second `sed` does inversion, appending first line to second line with `;` in between them. 
The case 2 `sed` is simply the second part of case 1 `sed`, but without `\n` at the end, since we don't need the empty lines in output.

Answer (score 0):

```
$ sed '/^$/d' File |sed -n 'h;n;p;g;p' | sed 'N;s/\n/ ; /'
Google ; http://www.google.com
Testing ; linktesting
```

Here first sed: remove empty lines; second sed: rotate every two lines; third one: join every two lines with ';'.